# How to split a string array into a new string array with remove duplicate

Tags: c#, arrays, split

I have a string and I don't know its count of items. I want to split this string array into a new array. After that I need to remove duplicate items as in the example below.

For example in the below: the word "hi" and "friends" goes twice, but we write them once in second array, it doesn't always have to be two over, sometimes 3 or more over and word "hi" and "friends" only for example, maybe other words goes two or more times).

For example;

```
string[] myString = {"hello friends", "hi guys", "hi friends", "how are", "123654 u?", "today man", "! ?", "maybe tomorrow", "5 2-", "99 1585126", "(/&&/& _____"};
```

I want to split it into a new string array like that (according space characater);

```
string[] new = {"hello", "friends", "hi", "guys", "how", "are", "123654", "u?", "today", "man", "!", "?", "maybe", "tomorrow","5" ,"2-" ,"99", "1585126", "/&&/&", "_____"} ;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `SelectMany` and `Distinct`:

```
string[] newArray = myString.SelectMany(s => s.Split(' ')).Distinct().ToArray();
```

If you want to compare in a case insensitive manner pass the appropriate comparer to `Distinct`:

```
string[] newArray = myString.SelectMany(s => s.Split(' ')).Distinct(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase).ToArray();
```

Comment: Might be better to use `Split(null)` to separate by any white-space instead of just one space...

Comment: @Johnny: Then use `Split()` without an argument. But in what way better? OP hasn't mentioned that he wants to include all white-space- or new-line-characters

Comment: @Rango in the way the code is more robust. I agree in this specific example it doesn't matter but generally...

Comment: @Johnny: not necessarily more robust, that depends on the business rules of OP which i don't know. If he says he wants to split by spaces(_"according space character"_) i don't provide a solution that silently splits also by other characters.

Comment: @Rango I forgot. I mark it right now. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a function:

```
public string[] GetDistinctArray(string[] input) { var str = string.Join("",input).Split(' ');return str.Distinct().ToArray();}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use "SelectMany" and "Distinct" with "Trim" :

```
var arr = myString.SelectMany(x => x.Trim().Split(' ')).Distinct(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase).ToArray();
```

Comment: Why with trim? What's the difference from the top answer?

Comment: Do you want empty string in your result?

Comment: Like what for example?

Comment: Example input : string[] myString ={"   hello   "};
unless "Trim()" result -> {"", "hello"}

Comment: Hmm. Thank you for answer.